# Python Pandas df how to transpose rows of 1 column to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have this df:

```
   Drug       Type          Count 
   drug1   DOWNREGULATE       2
   drug1   UPREGULATE         3
   drug1   UNIDIRECTIONAL     1
   drug2   UPREGULATE         5
   drug2   NEG_UNIDIRECTIONAL 1
   drug3   DOWNREGULATE       4
```

and I want this df:

```
  Drug    DOWNREGULATE  UPREGULATE  UNIDIRECTIONAL  NEG_UNIDIRECTIONAL
  drug1      2               3           1               0
  drug2      0               5           0               1
  drug3      4               0           0               0
```

This is the initial df:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Drug","Type", "Count"], data=[['drug1','DOWNREGULATE',       2],['drug1','UPREGULATE',3],['drug1','UNIDIRECTIONAL', 1],['drug2','UPREGULATE',5 ], ['drug2','NEG_UNIDIRECTIONAL',1 ],['drug3','DOWNREGULATE', 4]])
enter code here
```

How do I do this?